# Name That ...Name? 4

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I caused torsion in the 20th century in the Jewish land

I am mostly a food you could have a product of in your hand

I am well known by some as a British figure

I am more known by my nickname. Who figured?

Comment: Not sure, **`Irish Potato Famine`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be

> Benjamin?

I caused torsion in the 20th century in the Jewish land

> Could refer to Benjamin Netanyahu (had a stint as leader in the 1990s) or even David **Ben**-Gurion (first leader of the State of Israel)

I am mostly a food you could have a product of in your hand

> This could be referring to Eggs **Benny** (yes I know it's Benedict, yes this one is weak)

I am well known by some as a British figure

> This could be any major British figure, from Benjamin Disraeli to Benny Hill

I am more known by my nickname. Who figured?

> Most Benjamins aren't known as Benjamin, they're known as Ben or Benny (or in the case of Pres. Netanyahu, Bibi)

Answer (score 4):

How about

> Pig.

Torsion in the Jewish land:

> Jews don’t eat pig meat and the Israeli parliament outlawed breeding and selling of pigs in 1962, except for Arab-Christian areas ([source](http://blog.eteacherhebrew.com/israel-history/pork-prohibition-law-in-israel/))

You could have a product of in your hand:

> Pork knuckle is a popular pork dish.

Britain figure:

> Possibly refers to David Cameron (see [piggate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggate)).

More known by my nickname:

> Pig meat is generally called pork.

Comment: No, when I say a name, I mean a name you would give to a person. Now there might be people out there named Pig, but I've never heard of Pig as a name.

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

The scond line could be referring to

> Apple

Food, you could have a product in your hand